# python SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, exception, input, eval, syntax-error

So I have this code

```
m, b = eval(input())
```

the aim is to have a whole bunch of comma separated values inputted and then have python unpack the tuple into the variables

but when i run i get this error

```
    x, y = eval(input())
  File "<string>", line 1
    1,2

           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

what did i do wrong?

im using python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `eval` for things like this. It will be impossible to write it in a way such that the user can't break it (by mistake or on purpose). Do something like this instead:

```
data = input()
m, b = (int(var) for var in data.split(","))
```

Comment: lol in that case it instead returned     m, b = (int(var) for var in data.split(","))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1'